# I want to convert openlayers interface code to dojox code for pie chart use.So can we use same controls of openlayers map in dojox.If yes, how?

Tags: openlayers-2

Is their any way to add same openlayers map control to dojox map like navigation,panel,panzoom

Answer (score 1):

You can use dojox.geo.openlayers. Any examples [here](http://acuriousanimal.com/blog/2012/01/23/dojo-openlayers-new-challenges/). OL control can be added on map the following way:

```js
require(["dojo/ready", "dojox/geo/openlayers/Map", "dojo/_base/array"], function(ready, Map, array) {
      ready(function() {
          dojoMap = new Map("map");
          map = dojoMap.getOLMap();
          map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition())
....
```

Comment: but how to add controls...like in openlayers OpenLayers.Control.Navigation()  OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()....instead of these control what to use in dojox.geo.openlayer

Comment: I've added example of adding control on map.